# PostgreSQL Performance varies drastically from one server to another

Tags: postgresql

I am running PostgreSQL 13.4 and have a large table (~800M rows) for which I want to find the average and standard deviation of a column. I am running this query on two different servers running the same version of PostgreSQL with the same schema (verified by the diff tool in pgAdmin). The indexes on all the tables are identical.

The query I am running is as follows:

```
SELECT AVG("api_axle"."aoa") AS "mean",
   STDDEV_POP("api_axle"."aoa") AS "std" FROM "api_axle"
   INNER JOIN "api_train" ON ("api_axle"."train_id" = "api_train"."id")
   INNER JOIN "api_direction" ON ("api_train"."direction_id" = "api_direction"."id")
   INNER JOIN "api_track" ON ("api_direction"."track_id" = "api_track"."id")
   INNER JOIN "api_site" ON ("api_track"."site_id" = "api_site"."id")
   WHERE ("api_train"."time" >= '2022-06-12T19:43:32.164970+00:00'::timestamptz
          AND ("api_train"."direction_id" = '8a8b5df2-3b6a-4d95-8680-2df461d36d7b'::uuid
               OR "api_direction"."track_id" = '8a8b5df2-3b6a-4d95-8680-2df461d36d7b'::uuid 
               OR "api_track"."site_id" = '8a8b5df2-3b6a-4d95-8680-2df461d36d7b'::uuid 
               OR "api_site"."railroad_id" = '8a8b5df2-3b6a-4d95-8680-2df461d36d7b'::uuid)
          AND NOT ("api_axle"."aoa" IS NULL) AND "api_axle"."bogie_id" IS NULL)
```

On the slow run, execution takes around 3m and on the fast server under 100ms. Both servers have comparable hardware although the disk on the slow running one is around 2.5x slower than the fast one.

I would appreciate any insight on what could be causing this discrepancy in query plan and performance.

**EDIT:**

Result of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`:

Fast Server:

```
"Finalize Aggregate  (cost=7527555.19..7527555.20 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=313.413..317.169 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=1607 read=4627 written=651"
"  ->  Gather  (cost=7527554.95..7527555.16 rows=2 width=64) (actual time=312.562..317.140 rows=3 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        Buffers: shared hit=1607 read=4627 written=651"
"        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=7526554.95..7526554.96 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=293.727..293.762 rows=1 loops=3)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=1607 read=4627 written=651"
"              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=408.44..7526548.57 rows=1276 width=4) (actual time=201.987..289.682 rows=3212 loops=3)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=1607 read=4627 written=651"
"                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=82.87..9095.86 rows=78 width=16) (actual time=201.709..264.799 rows=222 loops=3)"
"                          Hash Cond: (api_track.site_id = api_site.id)"
"                          Join Filter: ((api_train.direction_id = '8a8b5df2-3b6a-4d95-8680-2df461d36d7b'::uuid) OR (api_direction.track_id = '8a8b5df2-3b6a-4d95-8680-2df461d36d7b'::uuid) OR (api_track.site_id = '8a8b5df2-3b6a-4d95-8680-2df461d36d7b'::uuid) OR (api_site.railroad_id = '8a8b5df2-3b6a-4d95-8680-2df461d36d7b'::uuid))"
"                          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 8726"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=165 read=235 written=19"
"                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=81.10..9090.13 rows=1493 width=64) (actual time=0.794..52.878 rows=8948 loops=3)"
"                                Hash Cond: (api_direction.track_id = api_track.id)"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=99 read=235 written=19"
"                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=79.13..9083.85 rows=1493 width=48) (actual time=0.660..32.094 rows=8948 loops=3)"
"                                      Hash Cond: (api_train.direction_id = api_direction.id)"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=96 read=235 written=19"
"                                      ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on api_train  (cost=76.20..9076.81 rows=1493 width=32) (actual time=0.433..11.273 rows=8948 loops=3)"
"                                            Recheck Cond: (""time"" >= '2022-06-12 19:43:32.16497+00'::timestamp with time zone)"
"                                            Heap Blocks: exact=96"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=93 read=235 written=19"
"                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on api_train_time_7204a1a7  (cost=0.00..75.30 rows=3583 width=0) (actual time=1.187..1.188 rows=26877 loops=1)"
"                                                  Index Cond: (""time"" >= '2022-06-12 19:43:32.16497+00'::timestamp with time zone)"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=21 read=49"
"                                      ->  Hash  (cost=1.86..1.86 rows=86 width=32) (actual time=0.219..0.223 rows=88 loops=3)"
"                                            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 14kB"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on api_direction  (cost=0.00..1.86 rows=86 width=32) (actual time=0.010..0.111 rows=88 loops=3)"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                                ->  Hash  (cost=1.43..1.43 rows=43 width=32) (actual time=0.124..0.128 rows=44 loops=3)"
"                                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                                      ->  Seq Scan on api_track  (cost=0.00..1.43 rows=43 width=32) (actual time=0.018..0.069 rows=44 loops=3)"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=1.34..1.34 rows=34 width=32) (actual time=200.592..200.596 rows=35 loops=3)"
"                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on api_site  (cost=0.00..1.34 rows=34 width=32) (actual time=200.494..200.538 rows=35 loops=3)"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on api_axle  (cost=325.57..96365.91 rows=1169 width=20) (actual time=0.027..0.076 rows=14 loops=665)"
"                          Recheck Cond: (train_id = api_train.id)"
"                          Filter: ((aoa IS NOT NULL) AND (bogie_id IS NULL))"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 233"
"                          Heap Blocks: exact=1142"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=1442 read=4392 written=632"
"                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on api_axle_train_id_8f2bba76  (cost=0.00..325.28 rows=25743 width=0) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=248 loops=665)"
"                                Index Cond: (train_id = api_train.id)"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=1408 read=1254 written=177"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=501 read=9"
"Planning Time: 9.733 ms"
"JIT:"
"  Functions: 119"
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 7.455 ms, Inlining 123.240 ms, Optimization 283.648 ms, Emission 193.846 ms, Total 608.189 ms"
"Execution Time: 369.168 ms"
```

Slow Server:

```
"Finalize Aggregate  (cost=15629658.70..15629658.71 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=193760.549..193863.020 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=991 read=12278213 dirtied=6 written=5"
"  ->  Gather  (cost=15629658.46..15629658.67 rows=2 width=64) (actual time=193753.058..193862.932 rows=3 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        Buffers: shared hit=991 read=12278213 dirtied=6 written=5"
"        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=15628658.46..15628658.47 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=193727.174..193727.188 rows=1 loops=3)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=991 read=12278213 dirtied=6 written=5"
"              ->  Hash Join  (cost=15039.93..15628644.49 rows=2793 width=4) (actual time=14030.963..193705.905 rows=3216 loops=3)"
"                    Hash Cond: (api_track.site_id = api_site.id)"
"                    Join Filter: ((api_train.direction_id = '8a8b5df2-3b6a-4d95-8680-2df461d36d7b'::uuid) OR (api_direction.track_id = '8a8b5df2-3b6a-4d95-8680-2df461d36d7b'::uuid) OR (api_track.site_id = '8a8b5df2-3b6a-4d95-8680-2df461d36d7b'::uuid) OR (api_site.railroad_id = '8a8b5df2-3b6a-4d95-8680-2df461d36d7b'::uuid))"
"                    Rows Removed by Join Filter: 116510"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=991 read=12278213 dirtied=6 written=5"
"                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=15038.17..15628500.30 rows=53735 width=52) (actual time=13700.147..193347.236 rows=119726 loops=3)"
"                          Hash Cond: (api_direction.track_id = api_track.id)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=928 read=12278213 dirtied=6 written=5"
"                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=15036.20..15628343.37 rows=53735 width=36) (actual time=13700.089..193314.073 rows=119726 loops=3)"
"                                Hash Cond: (api_train.direction_id = api_direction.id)"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=925 read=12278213 dirtied=6 written=5"
"                                ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=15033.27..15628192.43 rows=53735 width=20) (actual time=13700.031..193279.908 rows=119726 loops=3)"
"                                      Hash Cond: (api_axle.train_id = api_train.id)"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=922 read=12278213 dirtied=6 written=5"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on api_axle  (cost=0.00..15574239.21 rows=14826618 width=20) (actual time=2.209..190831.636 rows=12222952 loops=3)"
"                                            Filter: ((aoa IS NOT NULL) AND (bogie_id IS NULL))"
"                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 251852992"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=911 read=12277904 dirtied=6 written=5"
"                                      ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=14990.80..14990.80 rows=3397 width=32) (actual time=4.012..4.015 rows=8650 loops=3)"
"                                            Buckets: 32768 (originally 8192)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 2080kB"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=11 read=309"
"                                            ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on api_train  (cost=147.61..14990.80 rows=3397 width=32) (actual time=1.218..5.323 rows=25949 loops=1)"
"                                                  Recheck Cond: (""time"" >= '2022-06-12 19:43:32.16497+00'::timestamp with time zone)"
"                                                  Heap Blocks: exact=251"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=11 read=309"
"                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on api_train_time_7204a1a7  (cost=0.00..145.57 rows=8152 width=0) (actual time=1.171..1.172 rows=25990 loops=1)"
"                                                        Index Cond: (""time"" >= '2022-06-12 19:43:32.16497+00'::timestamp with time zone)"
"                                                        Buffers: shared hit=5 read=64"
"                                ->  Hash  (cost=1.86..1.86 rows=86 width=32) (actual time=0.050..0.052 rows=88 loops=3)"
"                                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 14kB"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                                      ->  Seq Scan on api_direction  (cost=0.00..1.86 rows=86 width=32) (actual time=0.018..0.028 rows=88 loops=3)"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=1.43..1.43 rows=43 width=32) (actual time=0.046..0.047 rows=44 loops=3)"
"                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on api_track  (cost=0.00..1.43 rows=43 width=32) (actual time=0.030..0.035 rows=44 loops=3)"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=1.34..1.34 rows=34 width=32) (actual time=324.272..324.273 rows=35 loops=3)"
"                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on api_site  (cost=0.00..1.34 rows=34 width=32) (actual time=324.238..324.249 rows=35 loops=3)"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=3"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=41 read=8"
"Planning Time: 6.060 ms"
"JIT:"
"  Functions: 128"
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 11.373 ms, Inlining 119.493 ms, Optimization 521.358 ms, Emission 330.504 ms, Total 982.728 ms"
"Execution Time: 193867.165 ms"
```

api_train table definition:

```
                         Table "public.api_train"
    Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id           | uuid                     |           | not null |
 time         | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 direction_id | uuid                     |           | not null |
 error_id     | integer                  |           |          |
Indexes:
    "api_train_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "api_train_direction_id_49569dab" btree (direction_id)
    "api_train_error_id_6312c8c6" btree (error_id)
    "api_train_time_7204a1a7" btree ("time")
    "unique_site_track_direction_time" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (direction_id, "time")
Foreign-key constraints:
    "api_train_direction_id_49569dab_fk_api_direction_id" FOREIGN KEY (direction_id) REFERENCES api_direction(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "api_train_error_id_6312c8c6_fk_api_bg6rejectioncode_code" FOREIGN KEY (error_id) REFERENCES api_bg6rejectioncode(code) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "api_axle" CONSTRAINT "api_axle_train_id_8f2bba76_fk_api_train_id" FOREIGN KEY (train_id) REFERENCES api_train(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "api_bogie" CONSTRAINT "api_bogie_train_id_089c4f60_fk_api_train_id" FOREIGN KEY (train_id) REFERENCES api_train(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "api_trainmodule" CONSTRAINT "api_trainmodule_train_id_9711466e_fk_api_train_id" FOREIGN KEY (train_id) REFERENCES api_train(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

**EDIT:**

The solution that worked for me in the end was to update the statistics target for the affected columns like so:

```
ALTER TABLE api_axle
ALTER COLUMN aoa SET STATISTICS 500;

ANALYZE VERBOSE api_axle;
```

Having better statistics was enough to help the query planner choose the superior plan that it was using on the fast server.

Comment: Have you run [Analyze](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html) on the 'slow' server?

Comment: Which storage type you are using on both server, both of them SSD, or old one HDD and new one SSD?

Comment: Both servers have two 500GB SSDs in RAID 0.

Comment: I've added `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` and another curious observation. The data is not exactly identical over the whole axles table (a few thousand axles in one that is not in the other over around 800 million rows) but it is identical over the time range that is being filtered on in the query.

Comment: On your slow environment, could you please run "set enable_hashjoin=off;" and then on the same session could you try to run same query again? And please share the explain plan.

Comment: @UmutTEKİN Setting this parameter definitely helped. I've included the query plan. If I set the date to `2022-06-01` now though it goes back to the slow query plan, even if I set `enable_hashjoin=off`. On the fast server changing the start date has no effect on the query plan and execution time is roughly the same.

Comment: That' s nice to hear that helps but the thing that I don' t understand is when you set to date 2022-06-01 it has same(slow) execution plan, even if you set enable_hashjoin=off. Could you share it' s plan, too? And, altogether it means that it did not help actually? One more thing, could you share definition of api_train table?

Comment: @UmutTEKİN I guess that's not the problem. I've added the api_train table definition and the query plan for `2022-06-01` with `enable_hashjoin=off`.

Comment: I don' t know why but you have recheck. You do not have lossy bitmap scan so, I think your index scans return rows that do not fits the predication and that is why you have recheck: https://www.pgmustard.com/docs/explain/rows-removed-by-index-recheck. Also, could you share values of ‘random_page_cost’ and ‘seq_page_cost’  parameters? One other thing is there might be skewness on your data. Did you check it? @LaurenzAlbe what do you think?

Comment: @UmutTEKİN I agree with you. The current value of `random_page_cost` is 4 and `seq_page_cost` is 1. That is something I played around with after reading [this](https://amplitude.engineering/how-a-single-postgresql-config-change-improved-slow-query-performance-by-50x-85593b8991b0). I set `random_page_cost`  to 1 like the article suggested for an SSD. It worked the first time I ran the query but after running it a few times it was back to the same query plan. I'm also thinking [this](https://gocardless.com/blog/debugging-the-postgres-query-planner/) might be related.

Comment: Running the same query after first time should be faster because of the cache but your' s behaviour is exactly the opposite :). I wonder what @LaurenzAlbe will say. Maybe switching to partitioned table may help if the case is like in the second link you sent. Yeah, I had read from https://amplitude.engineering/how-a-single-postgresql-config-change-improved-slow-query-performance-by-50x-85593b8991b0, too :).

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is at least that in the first (fast) plan, the index scan on `api_axle` is overestimated by a factor of 100. That probably makes that good plan look worse than it actually is (compare the total cost estimates).

You could improve the estimate by collecting more detailed statistics:

```
ALTER TABLE api_axle ALTER COLUMN aoa SET STATISTICS 1000;
ANALYZE api_axle;
```

If that isn't enough, try to create an index that makes the first type of plan seem even more attractive, in the hope that the optimizer will choose it:

```
CREATE INDEX ON api_axle (train_id) INCLUDE (aoa)
WHERE aoa IS NOT NULL AND bogie_id IS NULL;
```

Then `VACUUM api_axle` and try again. I am hoping for a fast index-only scan.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I did not get how did you find "by a factor of 100".

Comment: @UmutTEKİN `Bitmap Heap Scan on api_axle  (cost=325.57..96365.91 rows=1169 width=20) (actual time=0.027..0.076 rows=14 loops=665)`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe In the same api route I make the same query but for `bogie_id IS NOT NULL`. Won't adding this index throw off that query? I am playing with updating the statistics using `ANALYZE` and setting the sampling for the `aoa` column to take more samples like so: `ALTER TABLE api_axle
ALTER COLUMN aoa SET STATISTICS 5000;`. It seems to be making a big difference. I can now query all the way back to `2022-01-01` in around 1.5 seconds. The result is also repeatable. I assume there is a performance hit for this because of `auto-analyze`. Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: If more detailed statistics are enough to fix the estimate, great. Do that! See if a smaller value like 1000 is good enough.

Comment: Yes I made it 5000 as an exercise but from my tests now it appears 500 is enough. The line in the query plan you mentioned now looks like this: `Bitmap Heap Scan on api_axle  (cost=57.81..19212.12 rows=236 width=20) (actual time=0.025..0.063 rows=14 loops=621)"`. It's still off by a factor of 20 or so but it is much better! Thank you @UmutTEKİN and @LaurenzAlbe for your help.